# Why am I getting error while modifying "hydrogeo" function in R?

Tags: r, function, package

I am using "hydrogeo" package in R for piper plots.
I want to make some edits in the function for customization of plots.

However, when I use following command

```
trace("hydrogeo", edit=TRUE)
```

I get following error

```
Error in getFunction(what, where = whereF) : no function ‘hydrogeo’ found
```

I tried editing other functions using the same command and it worked, e.g.,

```
trace("semiMarkov", edit=TRUE)
```

How to resolve this error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that function specifically, but is there any reason why you can't just write a wrapper around the function?

Comment: I have no idea what a wrapper is.

Comment: Like rather than editing the function itself, writing a function that calls *that* function with whatever arguments you want to customize. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_function But if the issue is just that this function isn't actually in the package, then it's a typo/non-reproducible

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the error message `hydrogeo` is not a function of the `hydrogeo` package.

The available functions are:

```
library(hydrogeo)
ls("package:hydrogeo")
[1] "piper"      "piperPaper" "plot"       "testData"   "toPercent"
```

For example calling:

```
trace("piperPaper", edit=TRUE)
```

returns:

```
function (size = NULL, ...) 
{
  new("piperplot", call = sys.call(), ...)
}
```

#### EDIT: DIAGRAM CUSTOMIZATION

By reading the documentation there are some parameters that can be used to customize `size`, `symbols` and `color`. They are respectively: `cex`, `pt.pch` and `pt.col`.

From the example below

```
library(hydrogeo)

l <- list( Ca = c(43,10,73,26,32),
           Mg = c(30,50,3,14,12),
           Cl = c(24,10,12,30,43),
           SO4 = c(24,10,12,30,43))

lp <- piper(l)
plot( lp, main="Piper-Hill Diagram of Water Quality" )
```

we obtain the diagram

[image: base_diagram]

- by changing the `cex` parameter we obtain bigger symbols

  `plot( lp, main="Piper-Hill Diagram of Water Quality", cex=4)`

[image: big_diagram]

- by changing the `pt.pch` parameter we can choose other symbols. The available symbols are

[image: symbols]

So with the statement:

`lp@pt.pch = c(4,4,4,4,4)`

We obtain
[image]

- by changing the `pt.col` parameter we can set the colors

  `lp@pt.col = c(2,2,2,2,2)`

[image: symb_col_diagram]

Comment: In this particular package I want to customize the plots bu changing line type, and polygon color. 

However, while calling any of the package in `trace("PACKAGE", edit=TRUE)`, I do not get the specific line of code where I can make the edits.

Is there any way to edit specific lines of the package.

Comment: answered directly in the thread to add diagrams. Give it a check ;)

Comment: I appreciate your effort however, here, I require to change the line type, reduce the line width, increase the number of grid lines, and increase the size of tick labels on axis.

Comment: I see.. For those customizations I guess you should talk to the package developer. From CRAN I found this contact: Myles English myles at rockhead.biz.